# How can i do automatic login for facebook/twitter using Extjs or Grails

Tags: facebook, grails, extjs

I have the following screen
[image]

When the user enters some text and clicks on share button then a prompt window(not FB login page) should be opened in which user will enter his fb userid and password. Once he enters the details then textarea's text should be shared on time line.

Can anybody suggest me the way to achieve?

Regards
URL

Comment: This violates Facebook rules, you shouldn't ask user to enter login/password. Why you want it?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov It's the requirement from my client. Is there any way to achieve this kind of functionality

Comment: Is it for stealing user password?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov What does it mean?

Comment: I mean why client asked you to collect FB passwords?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Actually his requirement is that from his application user should be able to share messages to their respective walls without going to facebook/ without providing credentials in fb login page. As username and passwords are mandatory.. he'll read them using his own components. Like by adding usernamefield and password field in window and prompting the user to enter the details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39350/discussion-between-lahari-and-igor-artamonov)